# Parse tree structured json file to POJO class

Tags: java, json, jackson, gson

I have a JSON file that looks like this

```
{
  "deviceNodes": [
    {
      "header": "Mobiles",
      "metadata": "",
      "children": [
        {
          "header": "Apple",
          "metadata": "",
          "children": [
            {
              "header": "Apple iPhone 13",
              "metadata": "M1,M2",
              "children": []
            },
            {
              "header": "Apple iPhone 13 Pro",
              "metadata": "M1,M2",
              "children": []
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "header": "Samsung",
          "metadata": "",
          "children": [
            {
              "header": "Samsung Galaxy S22",
              "metadata": "M1,M2",
              "children": []
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "header": "Tablets",
      "metadata": "",
      "children": [
        {
          "header": "Apple",
          "metadata": "",
          "children": [
            {
              "header": "iPad 13",
              "metadata": "M1,M2",
              "children": []
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to parse this JSON file to a POJO class named `ViewModelPOJO`. Is there any any way I can achieve this using Jackson/Gson. I tried searching on web but didn't find any relevant strategy.

```
class ViewModelPOJO {
  List<DeviceNode> deviceNodes;
}

public class DeviceNode {
  private String header;
  private List<DeviceNode> children;
  private String metaData;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean you encountered an issue (if so, what specific issue), or did you really not find any code for how to do this? Because for both Gson and Jackson this is the standard use case; Gson: `new Gson().fromJson(json, ViewModelPOJO.class)`; Jackson: `new ObjectMapper().readValue(json, ViewModelPOJO.class)`

Comment: Also, the `DeviceNode#metaData` field should probably be lowercased (`metadata`) to match your JSON data, or you have to use Gson or Jackson annotations to specify the custom name for the field.

Comment: I guess that was the issue. I have to use `JsonProperty` annotation. After doing so parsing was successful.